# Best way to model state changes for point in time queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a system that needs to be able to find the "state" of an item at a particular time in history. The state is binary (either on or off). In this case it's to determine where to direct (to a particular "keyspace") a piece of timestamped data *as determined by the timestamp of the data*. I'm having a hard time deciding what the best way to model the data is.

Method 1 is to use the tstzrange with state being implied by the bounds of the range:

```sql
create extension btree_gist;
create table core.range_director (
    range tstzrange,
    directee_id text,
    keyspace text,
    -- allow a directee to be directed to multiple keyspaces at once
    exclude using gist (directee_id with =, keyspace with =, range with &&)
);

insert into core.range_director values
    ('[2021-01-15 00:00:00 -0:00,2021-01-20 00:00:00 -0:00)', 'THING_ID', 'KEYSPACE_1'),
    ('[2021-01-15 00:00:00 -0:00,)', 'THING_ID', 'KEYSPACE_2');

select keyspace from core.range_director
    where directee_id = 'THING_ID' and range_director.range @> '2021-01-15'::timestamptz;
-- returns KEYSPACE_1 and KEYSPACE_2
select keyspace from core.range_director
    where directee_id = 'THING_ID' and range_director.range @> '2021-01-21'::timestamptz;
-- returns KEYSPACE_2
```

Method 2 is to have explicit state changes:

```sql
create table core.status_director (
    status_time timestamptz,
    status text,
    directee_id text,
    keyspace text
); -- not sure what pk to use for this method

insert into core.status_director values
    ('2021-01-15 00:00:00 -0:00','Open','THING_ID','KEYSPACE_1'),
    ('2021-01-20 00:00:00 -0:00','Closed','THING_ID','KEYSPACE_1'),
    ('2021-01-15 00:00:00 -0:00','Open','THING_ID','KEYSPACE_2');

select distinct on(keyspace) keyspace, status from core.status_director
    where directee_id = 'THING_ID'
    and status_time < '2021-01-16'
    order by keyspace, status_time desc;
-- returns KEYSPACE_1:Open KEYSPACE_2:Open

select distinct on(keyspace) keyspace, status from core.status_director
    where directee_id = 'THING_ID'
    and status_time < '2021-01-21'
    order by keyspace, status_time desc;
-- returns KEYSPACE_1:Closed, KEYSPACE_2:Open
-- so, client code has to ensure that it only directs to status=Open keyspaces
```

Maybe there are other methods that would work as well, but these two seem to make the most sense to me. The benefit of the first method is the really easy query, but the down side is that you now have to update rows to close the state whereas in the second method you can just post new states which seems easier.

The table could conceivable grow into thousands or tens of thousands of rows, but will probably not grow into millions (but does the best method change depending on the expected row count?). I have a couple of similar tables with the same point-in-time "state" queries so it's really important that I get the model for them right.

My instinct is to go with Method 1, but are there any footguns or performance considerations that I'm not thinking of that would urge the use case towards Method 2 (or another method I haven't considered?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing a bunch of research on the topic I found that my case is a variation of a "Valid-Time State Table". See ch. 2 and ch. 5 of [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;?doi=10.1.1.636.6733&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Richard Snodgrass.

The support for these tables isn't great but it's not terrible either (at least PostgreSQL has tstzranges to work with). Method 1 of my post is largely sufficient - the main wrinkle is between the state table and other tables.

Since PostgreSQL doesn't have native support for these kinds of temporal tables, you have to build referential integrity yourself. There's a bunch of ways to do this, but for anyone in the future looking for some direction, here is an example of what that might look like for a referential query on two bitemporal tables:

```sql
create table a (
    row_id bigserial, -- to track individual rows
    id int,
    pov tstzrange, -- period of validity
    pop tstzrange -- period of presence
);

create table b (
    row_id bigserial,
    id int,
    pov tstzrange,
    pop tstzrange,
    a_id int
);

-- are we good?
with each_pov as (
    select bool_or(a.pov @> b.pov) as ok
    from a
    join b on a.id = b.a_id
        and upper(a.pop) is null
        and upper(b.pop) is null
    group by b.pov
) select coalesce(
    bool_and(each_pov.ok),
    (select count(*) = 0 from b where upper(pop) is null)
) from each_pov;
```

You can put the query into a constraint trigger on both the main table and the referenced table to get something approaching sequenced referential integrity for the current period of presence.

Answer (score 1):

No footguns with Method 1, just great *big* ***huge*** cannons. With that method how do you determine the current status. You need to scan each status change and for each one toggle the status, or perhaps use something like "count(*)%2" odd gives one state even another. What happens if any row gets deleted, or data purged and you do not know how many state transactions there were. With the Method 2 you retrieve the greatest date  and directly obtain the status.  
For myself I would do Method 3. That being Method1 + Method 2. Yes I would have a date range of the status and the status value itself. That gives me complex historical analysis as I have the complete history as well as direct access to current status at any time.

Comment: 1/2

> how do you determine the current status?

Via unbounded tstzranges when the status is "ongoing". So an `@> now()` or similar would work.

>What happens if any row gets deleted, or data purged and you do not know how many state transactions there were.

I think this is an issue with either method, since the primary purpose of the table is to query for the status at particular historical points of time. If you lose the historical data I think you are out of luck either way.

Comment: I think calling it a status is maybe confusing since the existence of a record is all the information you need in this case to determine "status". So method 1 + 2 is a bit weird to me since the status column is no longer relevant (there would be no records with any status except "open" because when it's closed there would be no record. A "closed" status is implied for all times not covered by a tstzrange)